# Express the length a, b, c, and d in the figure in terms of the trigonometric ratios of θ.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have memorized this chart and know that a= Sine, b= Tangent, c= Secant, and d= cosine.

However, while a and d make sense intuitively, I do not understand how Secant is c and b is tangent. Can someone explain? [image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the written formula,

$\tan \theta = \frac {\text{opposite side}}{\text{adjacent side}} = \frac b{\text{horizontal radius}} = \frac b1 = b$

The secant can be tackled similarly.

Answer (score 2):

As to the secant:

$$\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{\frac{\text{adjacent side}}{\text{hypotenuse}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c}}=c$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Given $\theta$, find the lengths of sides $b$ and $c$

[image]